# Line Segments for a Triangle

Tags: geometry, analysis

What are the requirements for three line segments to be able to form a triangle? What would be the proof of that? Thanks!

Comment: That the sum of any two of them is bigger than the third one. A really cutem, little theorem in Euclidean Geometry.

Comment: The endpoints of the line segments must be three distinct points pairwise shared by the line segments. As far as a proof goes, I'll have to think about that.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EHarmony provide a very successful service, based on 29 dimensions of compatibility, for determining whether three line segments will be able to form a stable and lasting triangle.

Comment: Hmm, the triangle inequality theorem says that "the length of each
side of a triangle is less than the sum of the lengths of the other sides.". So, if the lengths doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality they can't form a triangle. But that "if they satisfy they can form a triangle" doesn't need to be proved? I'm confused now. :X

Comment: @JoãoRimu, it follows from the law of cosines and continuity; given two of the sides, you can solve for an angle between them that makes the third side the prescribed length. There is surely a proof using only concepts familiar to Euclid, but I'm not expert in that.